# How to uninstall everything from my digital ocean droplet using putty?

Tags: digital-ocean

I want to uninstall everything from my digital ocean droplet using putty . How can I do this? I cannot rebuild or destroy droplet Because the confirmation mail sent to my clients mail but I dont want to ask  him again again.

Comment: What do you mean uninstall everything ?
I don't recommend to manually uninstall from digital ocean droplets (or) hack around. I guess the base image digital ocean provides has configurations that work very well with the Digital Ocean infrastructure. The ideal way to do this is restore a backup if you have one , or inform the client and recreate the droplet again.

Comment: uninstall means uninstalling apache,  php 7, mysql server, phpmyadmin. If i rebuild the droplet then everything start from scratch. But for rebuilding a confirmation mail also sent with a new password. I want to know is there any command like sudo apt-get uninstall -- which will remove everything from my server.

Answer (score 0):

after login as root user I used the following command and it removed everything

apt-get purge apache2 php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 mysql-server-5.6  php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json phpmyadmin